# Set roles based on invite link

Tags: python, discord

Is it possible to create multiple invite links in discord and set specific roles for those links?

For example:

```
inviteLink1 : ADMIN
inviteLink2 : MODERATOR
inviteLink3 : MEMBER
```

So if person A joins discord chat via `invitelink1`, he would have automatically obtain an `ADMIN` role, person B joins via `invitelink2` and is assigned automatically a `MODERATOR` role....

Comment: I'm pretty sure this functionality doesn't exist.  I don't see any way to create a link like this, or for a Discord bot to see information about the invite you used to join a server.  What you *can* do is have private channels for your various roles, and then use links to invite members to those channels.  Your bot can easily assign a role to anyone who posts in a particular channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible, but you can suggest this feature here: https://feedback.discordapp.com/forums/326712-discord-dream-land